# Get the digital signature of the msi/exe file - c#

Tags: c#, wix, ssl-certificate, exe, digital-signature

I have generated an MSI file for my application using Wix setup project.

I have created a certificate using OpenSSL and extracted the public and private keys from it.

I have signed the MSI using the private key of the certificate in the post-build events of the Wix setup project.

**Now how can I verify the signed MSI with the public key of the certificate on the client side to know if any changes were made to the file or not?**

Is it possible to extract the signature from the MSI file and verify it with the public key of the certificate on the client side?

I have tried so many ways which are just showing whether the file is signed or not but didn't verify the signature with the public key.

Comment: The Win32 API for verifying the signature is [`WinVerifyTrust()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wintrust/nf-wintrust-winverifytrust). There is an example linked at the bottom. You could p/invoke it or find a C# wrapper.

Comment: I want to verify with the public key of the certificate which was created by me and stored on the desktop.

Comment: I mean similar to the signature verification process in the XML file using the public key of the certificate.

Comment: [Verifying Publisher Name of a Signed Binary sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/security/cryptoapi/VerifyNameTrust/VerifyNameTrust/VerifyNameTrust.cpp). It's not exactly what you are asking for, but should do the trick. Basically let `WinVerifyTrust()` do the job of validating the signature and then check some fields of the certificate to determine if this is actually your certificate.

Comment: Related page: [How To Get Information from Authenticode Signed Executables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323809/how-to-get-information-from-authenticode-signed-executables)

Comment: If you're comfortable P/Invoking, see also [MsiGetFileSignatureInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msigetfilesignatureinformationw) which can return a PCCERT_CONTEXT for you to probe.